# Problems with Θ(n³) complexity on TMs with lower bounds by communication complexity arguments

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, lower-bounds, communication-complexity

One of the most used simple examples of application of [Communication Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity) is the $\Omega(n^2)$ lower bound for recognizing palindromes of length $2n$ on a *single tape* Turing machine.

> Is there a similarly simple example that
>
> - proves a lower bound of $\Omega(n^3)$ for another problem
> - that can be decided in time $O(n^3)$
> - on a single tape Turing machine
> - using arguments from communication complexity?

Comment: IIRC, the result cannot be extended to $\omega(n^2)$.
The reason is that the communication complexity of a function cannot be more than $n$. But I am not an expert. If you don't get an answer here you can move it to [cstheory.se] and hopefully someone will answer it there.

Comment: afaik nontrivial lower bounds (superlinear) are not proven for nearly any algorithms for TMs via any methods except "contrived" functions via diagonalization eg the [time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).